# How to store images in Firebase along with other information?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on a social media app for beer in Android that will have a similar look to twitter. Currently the user is able to submit a post which contains some information like the beer name, likes and dislikes about it, and their location along with a picture.

The string information is easy to submit to the realtime database and I currently have this working, but I am confused about the pictures. I know Firebase would like you to submit the pictures to the media storage part, but then when I retrieve the feed so each individual post is displayed, how can I keep it together so the correct strings are retrieved along with their relevant picture?

Comment: Have a look at the [Firebase codelab for Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) to see how you can combine Storage and Database to build a chat/image app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class beer with attributes (which you prefer) and also String attribute which would hold the image url for your particular object . Once you have uploaded your image to Firebase storage it gives you your image URL you can then use this URL and Upload in your database .

Suppose When you are uploading a Beer Object To your database 
ex

```
       databaseref.child("name").setValue("XYZ");
       //Add this extra line
       databaseref.child("ImageURL").setValue(DownloadURL/*Will be available on successfully uploading image to storage*/);
```

When you retrieve your Beer Objects from your database you can use ImageURL attribute to fetch the image associated with that object